# else if structure does not return true when it should

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm new to PineScript and I have a very weird issue with the "else-if" structure.

This code returns true, even though *arePreviousBarsInUpTrend(index)* is false.

```
isShootingStar(index) =>
    result = if (math.min(close[index], open[index]) <= low[index+1] and isCandleGreen(index))
        false
    else if (not arePreviousBarsInUpTrend(index))
        false
    else
        isLowerWickInsignificant(index) and isLongUpperWick(index)

    // Return the final result
    result
```

I've tried the arePreviousBarsInUpTrend(index) alone, it works fine.

As soon as I introduce the "else-if" structure, the method call is apparently ignored or overwritten.

I must be missing something.

Comment: Your code is syntactically backed by the documentation on [`if` used to return a value](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Conditional_structures.html#if-used-to-return-a-value), on [the logical operator `not`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#logical-operators) and on [Multi-line functions](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/User-defined_functions.html#multi-line-functions).  Can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: [There's another StackOverflow post of Pine Script v5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75620660/20594090) though, that states that your syntax didn't work for him either, but changing it slightly so you don't directly assign the ìf-else` to the variable but declare it beforehand worked. That might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries I found that the arePreviousBarsInUpTrend(index) method was not consistent. Pine script is very tricky when dealing with series.

as soon as you have a warning message like this one, you are very likely to run in some troubles:

> Warning at xxx:xx The function 'arePreviousBarsInUpTrend' should be
> called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to
> extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope

here is the explanation from the official documentation:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Functions_and_annotations.html

In my case, the exact same method was returning a different answer when moved up or down in the full script. I thought I was mad, but the context (series) was indeed changing. So the method would return true in a given call and would return false a bit later in the same script with the same input parameters, because the series had changed.

Fixing the warnings fixed my weird issue.